# Detekt | finished with non-zero exit value 255

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin, detekt

I am trying to run detektBaseline gradle task but facing following **Exception**

> Process ‘command ‘/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java’’ finished with
>   non-zero exit value 255

my project level gradle configuration for detekt

```
plugins {
   id “io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt” version “1.0.0.RC6-4”
}

detekt {
   version = “1.0.0.RC6-4”
   defaultProfile {
   input = “$projectDir/rlm/src/main/java”
   config = “$projectDir/default-detekt-config.yml”
   filters = “./resources/.,./build/.”
}
```

Any kind of help or guideline would be appreciated.

Comment: Is that all you see in the output? It seems like some previous log message would say what actually happened